# mouseLIstener "not working" in JPanel/JDialog

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

Since my previous post was a mess, I decided to repost it but hopefully much cleaner this time.

So here is the code I'm trying to work with:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class sample extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener
{
        JButton b1, b2;
        JPanel panel1;
        JDialog dialog;


public sample()
{
    dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setBounds (0,0,200,200);

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout (new FlowLayout());

    b1 = new JButton("B1");
    add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener (this);
    b1.addMouseListener (this);

    b2 = new JButton ("B2");
    panel1.add(b2);
    b2.addMouseListener (this);
    dialog.add(panel1);

             /* I tried this but it didn't work as well:
             dialog.addMouseListener(this);
             panel1.addMouseListener(this); */
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
    if (e.getSource () == b1)
        {
            dialog.setVisible (true);
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
    {
        setCursor (new Cursor (Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }
    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
    {
        setCursor (new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
   public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    sample s = new sample();
    s.setVisible (true);
    s.setBounds (0,0,200,200);
}
}
```

My goal is for the cursor to change to the hand cursor when the user hovers over B2, but it doesn't.
What am I missing?

Comment: *"Since my previous post was a mess, I decided to repost it"*  Don't do that! Instead *edit* the original post.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have deleted it already though

Comment: Well, hopefully that down-vote will remind you not to do that in future.  And in contrast to your earlier statement before you edited it, there *was* an answer, even if it was not especially relevant.  There was also a slew of helpful advice in comments.  You can choose to delete a question, but you can also choose to **reinstate it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem in next:

You set Cursor to `sample` instance(`JFrame`), not to `JButton`, for setting cursor on button change `setCursor (new Cursor (Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));` to `((JComponent)e.getSource()).setCursor (new Cursor (Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));`

Also for that purposes you needn't to use `MouseListener` you can just use:

`b1.setCursor(new Cursor (Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));`

Comment: Can I ask though why is it `JButton` and not the exact button itself? Is it because it's "easier" that way? You don't have to assign each button over and over again? :)

Comment: I can't catch your thoughts =(. Do you want to set this cursor, as default to all your buttons?

Comment: I put `JComponent` instead of `JButton` just  for reusing this listener in the future, for example that will be work if you add listener to `JTextField` or other `JComponent`, not just to `JButton`.

Comment: I'm being a little too vague here probably but okay thank you. =)